# HTTP 500 using FallbackResource and mass vhost config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, httpd.conf

## Context

I have Apache 2.2.15 configured for mass virtual hosting as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...irrelevant lines omitted
    VirtualDocumentRoot /srv/www/%-3+
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

`mkdir /srv/www/foo` makes `foo.example.com` available.

---

## Problem

HTTP 500 from all of `foo.example.com` when a `.htaccess` containing **only** a `FallbackResource` directive is in the vhost document root. Commenting out `FallbackResource` removes the error, but I want to use `FallbackResource`.

---

## Stuff tried

I confirmed the relevant module was loaded using `httpd -M | grep dir_module`. Oddly enough I still see `Invalid command 'FallbackResource', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` in the error log.

The filesystem is as simple as possible. There is only a "Hello, World" `index.php` and a `.htaccess`. Yes, permissions are fine.

```
/srv/www
    foo
        index.php <- 775, owned by apache
        .htaccess <- 664, owned by apache
```

I tried each of the following in `.htaccess`:

- `FallbackResource index.php`
- `FallbackResource /index.php`
- `FallbackResource foo/index.php`
- `FallbackResource /foo/index.php`

Also tried `<Directory /srv/www/foo>` even though that would not have worked anyway.

### New stuff tried given comments below

- `AllowOverride Indexes` raises `AllowOverride not allowed here` when entered into `<VirtualHost>` container.
- Confirmed `LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so` is in `httpd.conf`

Anything stupid/obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FallbackResource directive wasn't introduced until 2.2.16 as described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource). Upgrading Apache should solve your problem.

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid. Thanks for checking my blind spot.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `FallbackResource` in an htaccess file you need to allow the `Indexes` override. See the [mod_dir documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource). Try adding the override in your vhost config:

```
AllowOverride Indexes
```

You should also try looking in apache's error logs to see what's causing the 500 server error.

Comment: `Invalid command 'FallbackResource', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`, which is odd since the module is loaded. Also, `AllowOverride not allowed here` pops up when `AllowOverride Indexes` is added to vhost config.

Comment: Apache version 2.2.15, btw

Comment: @SageGerard The **Invalid command 'FallbackResource'** indicates that the module isn't loaded (mod_dir). You said that you tested with -M but there's no other way that I know of that you'd get that error message. Make sure that your `httpd.conf` (or maybe `apache.conf`) has a line similar to `LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The exact line you mention is in my `httpd.conf`. The problem persists. I may end up rephrasing my question in light of what we discussed here. In the meantime I added the extra detail to the question. `locate mod_dir` returns `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so`, so it is present on the system.

Comment: @SageGerard I guess now you just need to make sure that the apache binary that is being started is the same with that has mod_dir loaded, as opposed to some random statically compiled apache in some place like /opt/

Comment: I just ran `locate -r httpd$ | xargs file` to check on that. See output at http://shrib.com/N24v2Hl3. Also, I'm giving you +1 for sticking around to help out. Thanks! Going to poke around a bit more and see what's going on, because it looks like there is only one binary.